# Flink Oracle JDBC sink connector not loading the driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to create Flink JBDC sink to an oracle database. When run locally (from a junit test and minicluster) it works but when deployed in k8s it throws an exception saying it cannot find a suitable Driver. The Classpath is:

```
Classpath: /flink/lib/flink-cep-scala_2.12-1.13.5-stream1.jar:/flink/lib/flink-connector-jdbc_2.12-1.13.5.jar:/flink/lib/flink-csv-1.13.5-stream1.jar:/flink/lib/flink-json-1.13.5-stream1.jar:/flink/lib/flink-queryable-state-runtime_2.12-1.13.5-stream1.jar:/flink/lib/flink-shaded-netty-tcnative-dynamic-2.0.30.Final-13.0-stream1.jar:/flink/lib/flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:/flink/lib/flink-table-blink_2.12-1.13.5-stream1.jar:/flink/lib/flink-table_2.12-1.13.5-stream1.jar:/flink/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.16.0.jar:/flink/lib/log4j-api-2.16.0.jar:/flink/lib/log4j-core-2.16.0.jar:/flink/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.16.0.jar:/flink/lib/ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:/flink/lib/vvp-flink-ha-kubernetes-flink113-1.4-20211013.091138-2.jar:/flink/lib/flink-dist_2.12-1.13.5-stream1.jar:::
```

I tried multiple things:

1. Included the driver in the flink/lib directory and the flink-connector-jdbc connector was packaged within the the jar and `.withDriverName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")` /`.withDriverName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`
2. Included both the driver and the connector into the flink/lib directory and `.withDriverName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")` / `.withDriverName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`
3. I also tried to change the classloading configuration to `classloader.parent-first-patterns.additional: oracle.jdbc.`

but nothing seems to be working for me. The exception is:

```
failure cause: java.io.IOException: unable to open JDBC writer
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcOutputFormat.open(AbstractJdbcOutputFormat.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.JdbcBatchingOutputFormat.open(JdbcBatchingOutputFormat.java:115)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.GenericJdbcSinkFunction.open(GenericJdbcSinkFunction.java:49)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:34)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.open(StreamSink.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:442)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:585)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeRestore(StreamTask.java:565)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:650)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:540)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:759)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//SOMECONNECTION"
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.connection.SimpleJdbcConnectionProvider.getOrEstablishConnection(SimpleJdbcConnectionProvider.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcOutputFormat.open(AbstractJdbcOutputFormat.java:54)
    ... 14 more
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support in Flink 1.13 for Oracle via JDBC, that was only added in Flink 1.15

Comment: I see in the latest Ververica platform flink 1.15 is not supported. When can we expect the ververica platform to support flink 1.15?

Comment: I believe Ververica Platform 2.7.0 (with support for Flink 1.15) should be there in the next couple of weeks.